# How to get rid of blank space from iPhone notch on web page

Tags: html, css, iphone, next.js, frontend

Hi I don't know how to get rid of blank space on iPhone with notch on top screen. Do you know how to add background color other then the default white. My website is public. It's https://natanluczak.pl/ if you wanna check the code. I show you photo of it. [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeUUi.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the meta-setting *theme-color* in the head of your page.

`<meta name="theme-color" content="#4285f4">`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta/name/theme-color

---

But since it's an Apple device... you never really know if they support the industry standard right?! So if it doesn't help, maybe try the *web-app-status-bar* styling, but you're very limited to the colors, just default, black or black-translucent .

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">`

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html